# Using Iterator - java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, iterator

So, this returns me

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

and points to System.out.println line

```
Iterator<Autor> it = autores.iterator(); 
// Declaring a class iterator

public void listarAutores() {

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String aux = it.next().getNomeCompleto(); 
        // Get string from Class Autor method
        System.out.println(aux);
        // Printing that string
    }
}
```

Why it's happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: You probably use the underlying Iterable in the `while` statement.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you modify the collection between two calls to the method. For example:

```
listarAutores();
autores.add(anotherAuthor);
listarAutores();
```

You should create a new iterator in the method at every call or, even better, not use an iterator at all:

```
public void listarAutores() {
    for (Author a : autores) {
        String aux = a.getNomeCompleto(); 
        // Get string from Class Autor method
        System.out.println(aux);
        // Printing that string
    }
}
```

Comment: or `autores.forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.getNomeCompleto()));`

Comment: The second form may also use an iterator - just an implicit one.

Comment: @AndyThomas Yes sure, I meant not *explicitly* use an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `Iterator` into the method call. You probably modify the `Set` somewhere in between.